# Индикатор слайда bxslider

Tags: html, css, bxslider

Как переместить индикаторы текущего слайдера на само изображение, а не под ним? Пример на скриншоте:
[image: Пример]

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Уточните его добавив код слайдера

Comment: @Yuri По-моему, это вопрос про базовый вид слайдера http://bxslider.com Ссылка и код сделают вопрос лучше, но вопрос не `слишком общий`.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, ну ладно

Comment: Всё верно, вопрос был про базовый код слайдера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) позиционирует индикаторы абсолютно со свойством `bottom: -30px;`. А вам нужно какое-нибудь положительное значение для этого свойства. Например:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

Получится:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  .bx-wrapper img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt=""></li>
</ul>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```